# How to clear everything after certain character in string php?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have few functions that sanitize everything in get and post but this one must be bit more specific , I have an array that is producing links  like

```
array(
  1 => http://site/something/another/?get_something=1
  2 => http://site/something/another2/?get_something=1
)
```

also have a function that is sanitizing get and post but that function would clear everything from this array values so I am left with

httpsitesomethinganotherget_something1

can someone please help to match EVERYTHING  after `get_something=`
and clear it or replace it with get_something=1 , something like

```
$clear = preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $array[1]);
preg_replace("/get_something=".$clear."/i","",$array[1]);
```

Comment: So you want to remove, or replace, everything after the `=`?

Comment: @Jonahtan Samplson after  get_something=

Comment: how about parsing the url with parse_url() and sanitizing the "query" array value?

Comment: @tpaksu like said I have functions that do this and cant modify bunch of scripts because of 1 var

Comment: @Benn Using `parse_url` wouldn't require a great deal of rewriting.

Comment: @Benn, it will simplify your process if you explode your "query" with "&" and then get just the first one, then implode the array back again.

Comment: the example link is one of thousands ,   it can be anything from first example to   var=1&var2=5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `parse_url` but here is a regex implementation, in case you're curious:

```
$urls = array
(
    'http://site/something/another/?get_something=1',
    'http://site/something/another2/?get_something=1',
    'http://site/something/another/?get_something=1&foo=bar',
    'http://site/something/another/?foo=bar&get_something=1',
);

$urls = preg_replace('~[?&]get_something=.*$~i', '', $urls);

print_r($urls);
```

Should output ([demo](http://codepad.org/Fa5aKJwT) [[updated](http://codepad.org/a9fU4yhv)]):

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://site/something/another/
    [1] => http://site/something/another2/
    [2] => http://site/something/another/
    [3] => http://site/something/another/?foo=bar
)
```

Comment: this one cleans everything also /get_something=(.*)/

Comment: @Benn: Oh, I was under the impression that you wanted to delete everything *regarding the `get_something` argument*. To delete everything, it's even simpler, check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to parse the URL, your best bet is to use `parse_url`, lop off the query elements you don't want, and rebuild with `http_build_url`. Here's how I'd do it:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($linkArray); $i++) {
    // get original link and parse it
    $link = parse_url($linkArray[$i]);

    // replace the query portion
    $link["query"] = "get_something=1";

    // build the new URL
    $linkArray[$i] = $link["scheme"] . "://" . $link["hostname"] . $link["path"] . "?" . $link["query"] . "#" . $link["fragment"]

    // done
}
```

Comment: @Benn I've removed the `http_build_url` call, which requires PECL. This version is not as robust, but it should suit your needs.